# Watch not working when HTML loaded from Directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am loading a partial in Angular dependant on the route of the URL.

When I load the partial it loads, and responds to the Controllers functions. However I have a directive which has a watcher. This does not work when I use the

It works fine when I load the HTML inside the main page. I have a Plunker of this here
http://plnkr.co/edit/DK33pIrp0HyhUOjwm5X2?p=preview

Essentially clicking "hello" should change the $scope.origin and the watcher should then fire its event. It does not.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Custom Plunker</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>
      document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/coffee-script/1.1.2/coffee-script.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="directive.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MapCtrl">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
  </body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
var app;

app = angular.module("App", []);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  return $routeProvider.when("/", {
    templateUrl: "home.html",
    controller: MapCtrl
  });
});

this.MapCtrl = function($scope) {
  return $scope.clicked = function() {
    console.log("clicked");
    $scope.origin = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
    return console.log($scope.origin);
  };
};
```

directive.js

```
(function(angular) {
  var app;
  app = angular.module("App");
  return app.directive("leaflet", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      template: "<section id='map' class='map'></section>",
      scope: {
        origin: "=origin"
      },
      controller: function($scope, $attrs) {
        return $scope.$watch("origin", (function(newValue, oldValue) {
          return alert("its changed");
        }), true);
      }
    };
  });
})(angular);
```

home.html

```
<button ng-click="clicked()">hello</button>
```

how can I get this working?

edit: I have just made this pure JS and not coffeescript.

Comment: Where are you actually using your 'leaflet' directive? which watcher you are talking about, the one inside the directive or the one inside the MapCtrl?

Comment: i have updated http://plnkr.co/edit/DK33pIrp0HyhUOjwm5X2?p=preview the watcher inside the directive

Comment: Any joy, it works fine when partial is not loaded

Comment: I have updated to JavaScript and not cofffee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks so all who helped me find the issue.

This can be done by setting the

```
<button ng-click="clicked()">hello</button>
```

to

```
<button ng-click="$parent.clicked()">hello</button>
```

This is because the ng-view will be a child. This simple fix is now working.